# Mapping Sparse Lookup Table to Function Pointer Array in C on MicroController

Tags: c, embedded, function-pointers, lookup-tables, sparse-matrix

I just recently discovered the magic of function pointers in C and have been converting a rather large switch statement to a nice array of function pointers.  I want to use a simple look-up table to map into the function pointer array for easy function calling.

The problem is that the opcodes are all over the place with huge gaps in between them.  I don't want a huge array of 0's in order to space out the opcodearray to index with.  Memory is a big concern.

For instance... 
0x0000 is not an opcode
0x0001 is not an opcode
0x0002 is not an opcode
0x0003 is an opcode

I'm unable to point to the correct function without making the below OpcodesArray and having empty zeros in between the valid opcodes and non valid.

My example uses a communication interface that has a series of functions to call depending on the 16 bit opcode.  This opcode, needs to call specific functions.

Ex.

```
    const unsigned int OpcodesArray[] =   //array of opcodes
{
    0x0008,          //opcode  1
    0x000B,          //opcode 2...
    //... more here
    //... 
    0x00FF,              //opcode 45
    0x01D9,              //opcode 46



  };

void (*OpCodeFunctionPointerArray[TotalNumberOfStates])() = {  //function pointer array

    HOST_GEN_GET_REMOTE_NAME,     //0x0008
    HOST_GEN_SET_SCAN,            //0x000B
    //.....

    HOST_GEN_ERROR_IND,           //0x00FF
    HOST_SPP_SERVICE_CON,         //0x01D9
};


void Process_Packet(void)       /* Process and respond to received packet */
{

    States.OpCode = 0x00FF;   //Example input here

    ServiceStateMachine(States.OpCode);   //service packet

}

void ServiceStateMachine(unsigned int opCode)
{
    OpCodeFunctionPointerArray[opCode]();   //unable to do this because
                                                        //I don't want a huge array 
                                                        //full of zeros         
}


void HOST_GEN_ERROR_IND(void)        //This is the desired function to be called
{


}
```

I hope this has been enough information.  I just don't know how to take the opcode 0x00FF and have it call the appropriate function.  How do I take the 0x00FF and return the correct index without having a huge lookup table with a ton of zeros spacing out all the valid packets from the nonvalid.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should use an `unsigned short` array instead of an `unsigned int` one, if `sizeof(unsigned int) != sizeof(unsigned short)`

Comment: Just scan the first array until you find the opcode you're looking for, then use the index in the second array. Alternatively, you could use a `struct` to pair the two values together into one large array.

Comment: For now the opcode does not go past 0x01D9.  But that is 473 bytes in a lookup table that only has around 50 opcodes total.  It is a waste of space that is needed.

Comment: If your table is sparse, you aren't being efficient with your memory usage. Have you considered using a linked list for storage instead?

Comment: I was hoping to not have to iterate through the whole array to find the value.  With 50 opcodes that is quite cpu intensive and probably has no real performance benefits over the original switch statement...  Can you elaborate on the struct idea?

Comment: I'll post an answer (btw, you can use binary search to speed things up).

Comment: I have never used a linked list and will look into it.  Is there an easier more elegant way or am I doomed for a higher level construct or what?

Comment: Hash with look-next collisions would be easiest.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of having two separate arrays of related information, you can group each pair in a `struct`:

```
struct operation {
    unsigned short opcode;
    void (*function)();
};
```

Then, you can have an array of them:

```
struct operation opers[] = {
    { <opcode>, <function> },
    { <opcode>, <function> },
    ...
};
```

To look up an opcode, you can take advantage of the fact that they're sorted by opcode and use a binary search:

```
struct operation *op = bsearch(opers, <number of opcodes>, sizeof(struct operation), op_compar);
```

The `op_compar` function is used by `bsearch` to compare two elements of the array:

```
int op_compar(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const struct operation *op1 = a, *op2 = b;
    return op1->opcode - op2->opcode;
}
```

`bsearch` should run in logarithmic time, so it's very fast (compared to sequential search).

Comment: 1. Correction should be made on (struct operation[] opers) to struct operation opers[]

Comment: Also op_compar should be return ((op1 -> opcode)- (op2 -> opcode));

Comment: @bassplayer142 I'm surprised nobody else caught that earlier.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an array somewhat larger than the number of opcodes used (maybe 1.5 to 2X).
2. Create hash function to index into array.
3. Re-check entry from hash index.  If not a match, look to next entry.  Keep looking until you find the correct one.  With a big enough table, you shouldn't have too many collisions.

Comment: +1 I was about to suggest the same thing. Closed hashes, like you describe, are often fastest (because of few collisions) when the table is about half-way full.